# Transformation of Cubic Polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

I'm stuck on transforming this equation and am not sure where to begin. I know I need to define $x$ as some multiple of $u$ and somehow cancel the coefficient of the $x^2$ term but am not sure how to do it! Any help appreciated :)

Write the following in the form of $(u')^2=u^3 + au + b$, with $a$, $b$ constants?

$$x'^2+\frac{g}{l}x^3+cx^2+\frac{g}{l} x=0$$

$c$ is a constant of integration from a previous part of the question.

Comment: If you know you're supposed to write $x$ as a multiple of $u$, why not try it? Let $x=ku$, substitute that in, and see what $k$ has to be in order to get the coefficient of $u^3$ to be 1. Then you have to do $u$ to $u-r$ for some $r$ to get rid of the square term, so, try it and see what $r$ has to be. It's just algebra, you can do it!

Comment: Thanks, I'll work through what you've suggested and see where it gets me! @O.L. , at the moment I just need to transform into the form without the x^2 which I have stated in the question. The next step is to solve it and I will take a look at what you have suggested.

Comment: Please discard my previous comment - I have not understood the question correctly at the first reading.

Comment: Thank you for your help @GerryMyerson, I have figured it out! Though it has to be said, the constants aren't pretty :P

Comment: Good! Now you can write it up and post it as an answer; then later you can accept it. This helps clear up the Unanswered Questions queue.

Comment: Related: [Equation of motion for the pendulum](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446457/equation-of-motion-pendulum-using-w-eix)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=kv$. Then:
$$k^2v'^2+\frac{g}{l}k^3v^3+ck^2v^2+\frac{g}{l}kv=0$$
$$v'^2=-\frac{g}{l}kv^3-cv^2-\frac{g}{lk}v$$
So $k=-\frac{l}{g}$, giving:
$$v'^2=v^3-cv^2+\frac{g^2}{l^2}v$$
Now let $v=u+r$, giving:
$$u'^2=u^3+3u^2r+3ur^2+r^3-cu^2-cr^2-2cur+\frac{g^2}{l^2}(u+r)$$
We want the coefficient of $u^2$ to be $0$ (i.e $3u^2r=cu^2$). 

Thus $r=\frac{c}{3}$.
The cubic then has the form $u'^2=u^3+au+b$:
$$u^3+(\frac{g^2}{l^2}-\frac{c^2}{3})u+(\frac{g^2c}{3l^2}-\frac{2c^3}{27}),$$
where $a=(\frac{g^2}{l^2}-\frac{c^2}{3})$ and $b=(\frac{g^2c}{3l^2}-\frac{2c^3}{27})$.